# kendo grid UTC Date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an app that is used in several time zones. It is using a KendoGrid that receives a UTC date. It currently will display the UTC time in addition to the timezone offset supplied by the browser.

How do I go about automatically convert the time to the user's timezone with a ClientTemplate or something to that effect?

I don't want to actually execute the query in advanced since the grid has a lot of data and I'm leveraging the custom paging, sorting, etc., so converting the time before the binding is not a feasible solution for this scenario.

Note this is an MVC grid...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you make your DateTime properties in to DateTimeOffset properties then the framework should handle this "conversion" for you. 
Seems to work in our code :)